# In BibLaTeX, typeset all spillover bibliography that wasn't accepted by previous filters

Tags: biblatex

In `BibLaTeX`, I split bibliography into several sections using filters:

```tex
\defbibfilter{standards}{type=report}
\defbibfilter{books}{type=book}
\defbibfilter{articles-and-web-pages}{type=article or type=online}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[filter=standards, title=Standards]
\printbibliography[filter=books, title=Books]
\printbibliography[filter=articles-and-web-pages, title=Articles and Web Pages]
```

Now, I would like to create a separate section that would contain all references that weren't matched by my three filters.

I could create a fourth spillover filter that would complement my three filters:

```tex
\defbibfilter{spillover}{not ( type=report or type=book or type=article or type=online )}

\printbibliography[filter=spillover, title=Others]
```

However, that seems error-prone and difficult to maintain, because any change to my three filters and/or an addition of a new filter requires changing the spillover filter as well.

Is there a way to ask BibLaTeX to print all spillover references that weren't previously printed?

If not, is there at least a way to define the spillover in terms of other filters such as:

```tex
\defbibfilter{spillover}{not ( filter=standards or filter=books or filter=articles-and-web-pages)}
```

Otherwise, is there a way to define the three filters in terms of checks and then reuse the checks in the spillover filter? Anything to make things easier to maintain and more DRY, really (except that the syntax for checks seems so difficult to read compared to the syntax for filters that it may not be worth the trouble).

Comment: Can you provide a M(N)WE?

Comment: This is more of a conceptual question, I am not sure an MWE would be too helpful here. Nevertheless, the MWE would be the first code block in the question with standard BibLaTeX boilerplace around (`\documentclass{article} \usepackage{biblatex} \addbibresource{bibliography.bib} \begin{document} ... \end{document}` with `bibliography.bib` containing five sample records of types report, book, article, online, and some other type.

Comment: People are more likely to answer if you give them code they can copy-paste-compile to play with. Otherwise, somebody has to be interested enough to do that work first.

Comment: I will try to carve out the time. However, looking back now, this is more of a feature request (BibLaTeX does not seem to provide what I am looking for), so I may move the discussion to the BibLaTeX repo and self-answer here later.

Comment: If you do, please add a link here to the repo tracker page in the meantime.